# prevent double post client-side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

## TL;DR

the button btnAfdrukVoorbeeld needs to be disabled after 1 click, and re-nabled after downloading the file but OnClientClick isn't fired. I think the `UpdatePanel` is blocking this. Removing `Triggers` doesn't work as there's no postback.
Tried using js `__doPostBack("test", "")` but showed empty in `PageLoad()`
disabling the button inline `OnClientClick="this.disabled = true;"`works but prevents `OnClick` from being fired so that's not an option.

suggestions?

## Normal Post:

I've been trying to prevent a doubleclick posibility on a button that downloads the file using javascript.

unfortunately I have so far been unsuccesful, hense I'm writing this question.

in my eyes it should be relatively simple, but the `<asp:UpdatePanel>` with a `trigger postback` on the `button` prevents the `onClientClick` from being fired and thus my JS function is not called.

the `OnClick` function is being fired, so there's no problem there.

I have also tried inline like so: `OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;"` but this prevents the `OnClick` event from being fired, which is (as I later learned) expected.
also been fiddling with the `UpdatePanel` and the `triggers`, disabling them or changing the `UpdatePanel  Condition` to `always` but this didn't have positive effects.
Tried using js `__doPostBack("test", "")` but showed empty in `PageLoad()`...

The desired effect is that the button is disabled after a single click, the events are being fired and thus the page downloaded to pdf and the button is enabled again.

My first thought was to disable the button using JS and then re-enabling it at the "back-end".
The button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnAfdrukVoorbeeld" Visible="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
            OnClick="ButtonAfdrukVoorbeeld_Click" OnClientClick="processafhandelen"
            CssClass="ZAButton button_phone_bottom" Text="afdrukvoorbeeld" />
```

My Js:

```
function processafhandelen() {
    console.log('procesAfhandelen');
    var go_on = false;
    var imgSwirl = document.getElementById("<%= pnlSwirl.ClientID%>");
    var btnAfdr = document.getElementById('BtnAfdrukVoorbeeld');
    console.log(imgSwirl);
    console.log(btnAfdr);
    btnAfdr.disabled = true;
        if (imgSwirl.style.visibility == "visible") {
            //alert("Verzoek is al verzonden...., even geduld a.u.b!");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            console.log('disable btnAfdr')
            go_on = true;
            btnAfdr.disabled = false;
            showSwirl();
        }
        return go_on;
    }

    function showSwirl() {
        var imgSwirl = document.getElementById("<%= pnlSwirl.ClientID%>");
        if (imgSwirl) {
            imgSwirl.style.visibility = "visible";
            imgSwirl.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="DocumentOutPanelTextEditor DeleteTop" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divEditor" style='border: 0px groove #C0C0C0; width: 100%' runat="server">
            <telerik:RadPageLayout ID="RadPageLayout2" CssClass="desktoppagelayout formulieren" runat="server" GridType="Fluid" ShowGrid="false">
                <Rows>
                    <telerik:LayoutRow>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:LayoutColumn ID="LayoutColumn3" runat="server" Span="12">
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </telerik:LayoutRow>
                    <telerik:LayoutRow>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:LayoutColumn ID="LayoutColumn6" runat="server" Span="12">
                                <input id="varUnsaved" type="hidden" name="varUnsaved" runat="server" />
                                <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="ramCorr" runat="server">
                                    <AjaxSettings>
                                        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="UDPCorrUitgaand">
                                            <UpdatedControls>
                                                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlButtonsCorr" />
                                            </UpdatedControls>
                                        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                                    </AjaxSettings>
                                </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlCorrUitgaand" Height="80%" Width="100%" runat="server">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UDPCorrUitgaand" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <%--<telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditorCorrUitgaand" runat="server" Skin="Office2010Silver" EditModes="All"
                                        EnableResize="False" ToolsFile="~/App_Data/RadEditor/ToolsFile_CU.xml" Width="100%" Height="1150px"
                                        OnClientLoad="onClientLoad" OnClientPasteHtml="OnClientPasteHtml" OnClientCommandExecuting="OnClientCommandExecuting">
                                        <Content>                
                                        </Content>
                                    </telerik:RadEditor>--%>
                                            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptradeditor.js"></script>
                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                TelerikDemo.rwUploadId = "<%=RadWindow1.ClientID%>";
                                                TelerikDemo.rnMessagesId = "<%=RadNotification1.ClientID%>";
                                                TelerikDemo.reId = "<%=RadEditorCorrUitgaand.ClientID%>";
                                            </script>
                                            <div class="container no-bg">
                                                <telerik:RadEditor
                                                    ID="RadEditorCorrUitgaand" runat="server" ToolbarMode="RibbonBar" Style="width: 875px; min-height: 1000px; height: 1000px"
                                                    EnableTrackChanges="true" EnableComments="true" ToolsFile="~/App_Data/RadEditor/word-like-tools-corr.xml"
                                                    EditModes="All" OnClientLoad="onClientLoadCorr" OnClientCommandExecuting="OnClientCommandExecuting" Language="nl-NL"
                                                    ImageManager-MaxUploadFileSize="512000" ExternalDialogsPath="~/App_Data/RadEditor/EditorDialogs">
                                                    <TrackChangesSettings CanAcceptTrackChanges="true" />
                                                    <DocumentManager ViewPaths="~/Files" UploadPaths="~/Files" />
                                                    <SpellCheckSettings DictionaryLanguage="nl-NL" />
                                                    <ExportSettings OpenInNewWindow="true" />
                                                    <ImageManager EnableAsyncUpload="False" EnableImageEditor="True" ContentProviderTypeName="FileStorageContentProvider, App_CODE" ViewMode="Grid" SearchPatterns="*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.bmp" />
                                                    <Content></Content>
                                                </telerik:RadEditor>
                                            </div>
                                            <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" Title="Upload File" Behaviors="Close, Move" VisibleStatusbar="false" AutoSize="true">
                                            </telerik:RadWindow>
                                            <telerik:RadNotification ID="RadNotification1" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="150px" Title="An error occured" TitleIcon="warning"
                                                ContentIcon="info" Position="Center" AutoCloseDelay="5000" EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadow="true">
                                            </telerik:RadNotification>
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="RadFont" runat="server" />
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/loading_small.gif" />
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </telerik:LayoutRow>

                </Rows>
            </telerik:RadPageLayout>

            <telerik:RadPageLayout ID="RadPageLayout3" CssClass="desktoppagelayout knoppen footerPhone" runat="server" GridType="Fluid" ShowGrid="false">
                <Rows>
                    <telerik:LayoutRow Style="margin-top: 10px">
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:LayoutColumn Span="5">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkVergrendelen" runat="server" /><asp:Label Text="vergrendelen" runat="server" CssClass="label" />
                            </telerik:LayoutColumn>
                            <telerik:LayoutColumn ID="LayoutColumn7" runat="server" Span="6" Style="padding-left: 53px" CssClass="desktopcontainer-buttons">
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlButtonsCorr" runat="server" Visible="true">
                                    <div id="divfoutmeldingen" class="divfoutmeldingen" runat="server" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <asp:Panel ID="PanelFout" Visible="false" runat="server" CssClass="error">
                                            <asp:Button ID="imgerrormelding" runat="server" CssClass="spritebase-no-block sprite-error" disabled />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblError" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                                        </asp:Panel>

                                        <asp:Panel ID="PanelOpgeslagen" Visible="false" runat="server" CssClass="success">
                                            <asp:Button ID="imgmelding" runat="server" CssClass="spritebase-no-block sprite-success" disabled />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblOpgeslagenBericht" runat="server" Text="De gegevens zijn opgeslagen." />
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </div>
                                </asp:Panel>

                                <asp:Button ID="btnVerwijderen" Visible="true" runat="server" zafunction="delete"
                                    OnClick="btnVerwijderen_Click" CssClass="ZAButton button_phone_bottom" Text="verwijderen" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAnnuleren" Visible="true" runat="server"
                                    OnClick="btnAnnuleren_Click" CssClass="ZAButton button_phone_bottom" Text="annuleren" />
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnAfdrukVoorbeeld" Visible="true" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                    OnClick="ButtonAfdrukVoorbeeld_Click" OnClientClick="processafhandelen" CssClass="ZAButton button_phone_bottom" Text="afdrukvoorbeeld" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnOpslaanDoorgaan" zafunction="save" Visible="true" runat="server"
                                    OnClick="btnOpslaanDoorgaan_Click" CssClass="ZAButton button_phone_bottom" Text="opslaan" />
                                
                                                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSwirl" style="visibility:hidden;">
                                                        <asp:Image ID="imgSwirl" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="~/Images/loading_small.gif"/> Even geduld a.u.b.
                                                    </asp:Panel>
                            </telerik:LayoutColumn>

                        </Columns>
                    </telerik:LayoutRow>
                </Rows>
            </telerik:RadPageLayout>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnAfdrukVoorbeeld" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

C#:

```
 protected void ButtonAfdrukVoorbeeld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Patient patient = (Patient)Session["Patient"];
    Relatie relatie = null;
    if (patient == null)
    {
        patient = new Patient(SessionObject.XPSession);
    }

    radWindowManagerEmail.Windows.Clear();
    Sjabloon sjabloon = null;
    if (DropDownListSjabloon.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        sjabloon = SessionObject.XPSession.FindByKey<Sjabloon>(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListSjabloon.SelectedValue));
    }

    string nieuweContent = RadEditorCorrUitgaand.Content;
    if (sjabloon != null && sjabloon.Groep.Velden != null)
    {
        string[] sjabloonvelden = sjabloon.Groep.Velden.Split(new char[] { ';' });
        foreach (string veld in sjabloonvelden)
        {
            //**Do stuff**
        }

        string dir = Utils.GeefDataFolderNaam(true, @"Documenten\Uitgaand\");
        string FileDownloadName = "afdrukvoorbeeld";
        Gebruiker gebruiker = (Gebruiker)Session["Gebruiker"];
        Utils.createPDFNoFile(nieuweContent, FileDownloadName);
        updPanel2.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a random but persistent value to the data submissions. If you get two requests with the same random value in them, you can ignore the second request.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm sorry I don't think i quite understand, how would I achieve this? Do you mean add an attribute to the button and read it out in the c# code? or do I add it to the response and read it out before the response.Flush is fired?

Comment: The backend should be checking for it. This is called an "idempotency token" (also "idempotency key"). You only process requests with a different one of those which means that you won't process a double submission, no matter how it happens.

Comment: but how would I remove the token after completion when the code ends at response.Flush?

Comment: You probably don't. You can just keep it in a database of some description. You can also clean up old ones periodically, if needed but it's not required.

Comment: sorry for the late response, this didn't solve my problem unfortunately